# Drupal 7 session handling

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to login into Drupal  from a remote site using the REST api method. I need to get the session ID for the authenticated user from Drupal.  I am using Drupal 7. 
Please help

Comment: Have you looked at the Services module? http://drupal.org/project/services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I defined to create session to store ID for the authenticated user at login and registration time.

```
/*
* At Login time to create session to store user id.
*
* Implement hook_user_login()
*/
function module_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $account->uid;
}

/*
* At Registration time to create session to store user id.
*
* Implement hook_user_insert()
*/
function module_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $account->uid;
}
```